# Почему метод apply библиотеки pandas не работает, если к DataFrame ранее применена группировка по двум столбцам и арифметическая операция

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть набор данных о продажах, взятых с Kaggle.
Хочу найти по 3 самых продаваемых товара в каждой стране.
Использую следующий код `Python`:

```
def top(df, n=3, column="Quantity"): #Функция для выбора 3-х наибольших значений
    return df.sort_values(column, ascending=False)[:n]
```

Дальше группировка и суммирование по выбранным столбцам с использованием библиотеки `pandas` - результат пока ожидаемый

```
grouped_by_country = data_ecom.groupby([data_ecom['Country'], data_ecom['StockCode']])

grouped_by_country.agg({'Quantity': 'sum'})
```

Но попытка применить функцию `top` методом `apply` все ломает:

```
grouped_by_country.agg({'Quantity': 'sum'}).apply(top)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ```
> Series.sort_values() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional
>     arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
> ```

При этом, если убрать метод `agg` и оставить только  одну группировку то функция `top` работает так, как ожидаю:

```
grouped_by_country = data_ecom[['Quantity']].groupby([data_ecom['Country']])
grouped_by_country.apply(top)
```

Уже несколько дней пытаюсь разобраться, не понимаю, в чем проблема.

Comment: Так то в ошибке у вас всё написано - вы передаёте серию, а не датафрейм, у серии одна колонка, её имя не нужно задавать в `sort_values`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вместо

   ```
   grouped_by_country.agg({'Quantity': 'sum'})
   ```

   примените

   ```
   grouped_by_country = grouped_by_country.agg({'Quantity': 'sum'})
   ```
2. Вместо

   ```
   grouped_by_country.apply(top)
   ```

   примените просто

   ```
   top(grouped_by_country)
   ```

Затем **все будет работать так, как вы хотели**.

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Команда

   ```
   grouped_by_country.agg({'Quantity': 'sum'})
   ```

   это только выражение, которое вычисляется и **затем выбросится**, потому что вы его **не сохраняете** в никакой переменной.

   Вы наверно хотели его результат **сохранит в той же переменной** `grouped_by_country`.
2. Метод `.apply(top)` делает не то, что вы хотели — он применяет функцию `top()` **отдельно к каждому столбцу** датафрейма.

---

*Примечание к пункту 2:*

Когда вам жалко за формой применения функции `top()` в (неправильном) виде

```
grouped_by_country.apply(top)
```

используйте вместо метода `.apply()` метод `.pipe()`:

```
grouped_by_country.pipe(top)
```

Это то же самое, как `top(grouped_by_country)`.

---

*Другие примечания:*

- В определении вашей функции `top()` вы можете вместо долгого

  ```
  return df.sort_values(column, ascending=False)[:n]
  ```

  использовать метод `.nlargest()`:

  ```
  return df.nlargest(n, column)
  ```
- Вам вообще не надо писать функцию `top()`, т.к. вы тот же метод `.nlargest()` можете применить прямо к вашему датафрейму `grouped_by_country`:

  ```
  grouped_by_country.nlargest(3, "Quantity")
  ```

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! Попробовал применить Ваши рекомендации.
В результате было отобрано три самых продаваемых товара только одной страны. Ожидал, что будут отобраны 3 самых продаваемых товаров по всем странам.

Comment: @МихаилР, это не был комментарий, а ответ.:-) И я в нем точно ответил на ваш вопрос из заголовка. Меня это — как вы видите — стояло немало усилия и времени, чтобы вам помочь. Потому я думаю, что я заслужу от вас оценки в виде принятия моего ответа (клик на галочку налево от него). — Затем вы можете задать другой, новый вопрос.

Comment: Извините, но, на мой взгляд, Вы не ответили на вопрос "Почему метод apply библиотеки pandas не работает, если к DataFrame ранее применена группировка по двум столбцам и арифметическая операция" и Ваши предложения не помогли в решении моей задачи )) за короткое nlargest - спасибо))
Но я уже разобрался - дело было в особенности применения операций к сгруппированным groupby объектам) в моем случае правильно было применять функции группировки, суммирования, сортировки и среза внутри функции apply. И apply должен был примениться к объекту groupby

Comment: @Михаил Р: Видят, вы умный человек.